# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock' (2) in my Mac OS BigSur

Tags: mysql, mariadb, macos-big-sur

I am trying to re-configure my local dev env in my Mac OS BigSur by following the writing [here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-mysql-vhost-apc).

Once I am trying to install and run it installed properly and I am being able to run:

- `brew services start mariadb`
- `brew services stop mariadb`
- `brew services restart mariadb`

and all these command works well with proper success message.

But when I try to change the initial password with the command `sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation` or `sudo mysql -u root`

the following error occurred.

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/usr/local/mariadb/data/mariadb.sock' (2)`

I tried so many ways to fix it by reading similar issues in StackOverflow and some other forums but so far no good result came.

**Update:**

System error log is being shared as per the suggestion of @danblack

```
Oct 23 14:58:55 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb[95257]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Oct 23 14:58:55 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Oct 23 14:58:55 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb[95256]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Oct 23 14:58:55 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mariadb): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Oct 23 14:59:05 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[95424]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /usr/local/mysql: 20G165: xpcproxy + 23787 [673][42C436DB-45AD-3EE7-AD04-D60F7FCAA4AD]: 0x2

Oct 23 14:59:05 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[95424]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78

Oct 23 14:59:05 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Oct 23 14:59:05 Amans-MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Session adoption is only allowed in user domains.
```

**Update: My_Print_Default Content**

```
Amans-MacBook-Pro:~ amanullah$ /usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults 
--mysqld
--bind-address=127.0.0.1
--mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Does anyone have some similar experience? can share any solution?

Comment: ,MariaDB isn't started. Read and share MariaDB's error log.

Comment: @danblack I have updated the post with error log. Please check and guide if you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have both MySQL and MariaDB from home brew configured to start. What is the error-log contents (filename from `/usr/local/bin/my_print_default --mysqld`)

Comment: hi @danblack I have updated the post with content of /usr/local/bin/my_print_default file. for your information the --mysqld flag shows some error, like "nano: unrecognized option `--mysqld'" , "Unknown option argument: "--mysqld""

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults` should be an existing program to run (sorry for typo), with the `--mysqld` as its arg. It will output sometime including `--log-error={filename}`. Look in the `{filename}`.

Comment: hi @danblack just updated the post with the "/usr/local/bin/my_print_default --mysqld" command and output.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults --mysqld`. Attention to detail, like I should have been on the original comment, plural, with an `s` a the end.

Comment: hi @danblack, I have updated again.

Comment: hi @danblack the output of the command is: Amans-MacBook-Pro:~ amanullah$ /usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults 
--mysqld
--bind-address=127.0.0.1
--mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

Comment: I've almost lost interest so repinging won't help. `mysqlx-bind-address` is MySQL only setting and not mariadb so if that's left in a config file somewhere, remove it. If that doesn't work. find your error log. I don't have a Mac or OSX so I can't help further.